# Python string to json with escaping double quotes

Tags: python, json, string, type-conversion

I have a string that I need to be converted to json. It has the following structure:

```
[{"name": "Karolina", "company": "Shop "Karolina""}]
```

As you can see there can be double quotes inside the string that should be escaped while converting. How can I convert this string to json?

Comment: [The json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) will do the whole conversion and take care of escaping quotes.

Comment: Do you mean you are starting with invalid JSON and trying to parse it? Because the solution to that is to fix whatever gave you invalid JSON in the first place.

Comment: Yes, exactly, the string has an invalid json structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's invalid Python. Correct python (and also JSON) would be

```
s = [{"name": "Karolina", "company": "Shop \"Karolina\""}]
```

Python, but not json, allows for

```
s = [{'name': 'Karolina', 'company': 'Shop "Karolina"'}]
```

As khelwood mentioned, the better way to convert python into JSON is with standard namesake library

```
import json
json.dumps(s)
```

other libraries might work too.

PS. You can try to code JSON manually yet it might be challenging task for large data

```
my_json_string = r'[{"name": "Karolina", "company": "Shop \"Karolina\""}]
```